# Did the default instance management mode for WCF change from Per Call to Per Session since WCF's release?

Tags: .net, wcf

In this article ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx#S2)), Juval Lowy states that PerCall is the default.  However, in the current documentation ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx)), the default is described as PerSession.

Is this something that changed since WCF was released?  If so, does anyone know the justification?

All of the documentation I've read about WCF to date says to avoid stateful (PerSession) services in favor of stateless (PerCall) services.

Am I just looking at this wrong maybe?

Thanks for any illumination!

UPDATE: I actually found exactly what I was looking for and added it as an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found the answer I was looking for:

Check out this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edpinto/archive/2006/10/16/wcf-instancing-mode-default-is-instancecontextmode-persession.aspx).

We changed this in the June CTP.  Here's the reasoning:

"With PerCall, users who required a session in their ServiceContract would get a session that lasted the duration of a single call unless they changed the InstanceContextMode to PerSession.

With the ***new*** default of PerSession, users who require a session will get instance lifetime tied to session channel lifetime, as they expect.  Users who don't require a session in their contract will still get instance lifetime that looks like PerCall.  The benefit of this change is that users get the instance lifetime they expect once they set session requirements on the contract, without having to tweak the InstanceContextMode."

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic is that the ServiceBehavior default is perSession however the session for the ServiceContract is NotAllowed making it in effect per call.

Looking at the MSDN link you can see for all versions of the framework the ServiceBehavior default has always been perSession.

Answer (score 1):

I can assure you that the default behaviour for basicHttp channels is PerCall simply because basicHttp bindings do not support PerSession instantiation. I have a service running with that configuration. 
See [this blog](http://suntsu.ch/serendipity/index.php?/categories/11-Azure)

Answer (score 0):

It certainly changed. I have recently noticed this fact while discussing about our legacy WCF app. In the book *MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-503) MS .NET Framework 3.5 WCF*, Chapter 10 (Sessions and Instancing) Instancing Modes topic, the author says:

> **Per call instancing is the default mode for WCF.** There are a number of reasons for making this particular choice. For the developer, per call mode requires the least amount of consideration given to concurrency. If each request has its own copy of the object, there is no need to worry about a shared value being updated in a non-atomic manner.

Please note that this book is about **WCF 3.5.**

Up to date Microsoft docs on the other hand states that the **default value is PerSession.**