# Create and configure core logic in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-ria-services, entry-point

Created simple WCF Service project with some services. 
How to define project entry logic as `Main()` in console app, `Application_Start()` in WPF App.cs or in ASP.NET global.asax.cs?

Comment: there is no Main() or other starting point, you are configuring services and you can call them from outside

Comment: Are you mean that I can't use services to host some logic except communication?

Comment: You can store logic, but they are stateless http://stackoverflow.com/a/6050685/1714342

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
So, I'm now trying classic static initializer-core pair. Maybe it will work now, I've used it two years ago with WCF Domain for simple chatting engine.

Answer (score 0):

Put the logic in the static constructor of the Service class. If Service is IService1, put it in

```
static Service1() {

}
```

It will be called only once one service start.